# regex, how to find last none alpha char excluding dollar and underscore

Tags: php, regex

Iam trying to get the last word/char (==alphanumeric) from a string. (I am hopeless with regex (I cant wrap my head around it at this moment). I found a few regulair expresions and used it to make the following:

```
$sName=" $stackOverFlow  *^ %";
$iNameBegin=0;

if (preg_match_all('/(\pL)\PL*$/u', $sName, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) > 0) {   
   $lastMatch = $matches[0][count($matches[0])-1];
   $sName=substr($sName,0,$lastMatch[1]+1);
}
if (preg_match_all('/[\W*$]/', $sName, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) > 0) {
    $lastMatch = $matches[0][count($matches[0])-1];
    $iNameBegin=$lastMatch[1]+1;
}

$sName=substr($sName,$iNameBegin);
```

Which works... by using:

1. strRpos to find the last alpha char (first if statement) in $sName
2. cutting off $sName at this position
3. use strRpos to find the last NON alpha char in the cut off string (second if statement)
4. cutoff $sName from pos of last NON alpha char

This works, but I need it to see the dollar sign $ as an alpha char (aswell as "_", but this allready happens). 
in short: I want the found name to be "$stackOverFlow" instead if "stackOverFlow"

Now I've spend a lot of time googling an answer and even considered finaly reading up into regex to understand and make my own (but I dont have the time/spirit to do some hours of learing atm). So perhaps someone can show me how to see the dollar sign as a alpha char and perhaps and beter method to get the last alphanumeric word/char from a string

Comment: So do you want the last character which is not alphanumeric or `$` or `_` ? Or the last character which is alphanumeric ?

Comment: Do you mean `alphanumeric` or `alphabetic`?

Comment: Yes the last char which is not alphanumeric or "&" "_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand entirely, but I think you need a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
if (preg_match('/[\w$](?=[^\w$]*$)/', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
[\w$]    # Match an alnum or $
(?=      # only if the following can be matched from here on:
 [^\w$]* # Any number of characters except alnums and $
 $       # until the end of the string
)        # End of lookahead
```

Comment: It took me a while to figure it out, but I did. thank you! And I have bookmarked your link for later